Filebeat output using SAS token to azure eventhub
I want to send my filebeat logs to eventhubs using SAS token, earlier we wanted to use Kafka output but we came to know Kafka doesn't support SAS tokens, so now is there some way we can send data using SAS token, for example some plugin for filebeat which supports http output so we can use SAS tokens directly?

Filebeat does not natively support an HTTP output.
However, there is a workaround to send logs to Azure Event Hubs using the logstash output plugin.
You can set up Filebeat to send logs to Logstash, which in turn will send them to Azure Event Hubs using an HTTP plugin in Logstash.
Filebeat should look like:
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

Logstash:
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  http {
    url => "https://<YourNamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<YourEventHub>/messages"
    http_method => "post"
    headers => {
      "Authorization" => "SharedAccessSignature sr=<your-event-hub-url>&sig=<your-signature>&se=<expiry>&skn=<your-sas-key-name>"
      "Content-Type" => "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"
    }
    format => "json"
  }
}

Still this is not very nice workaround but it should work if you can't find solution for direct data ingest to eventhub.
